# Checking whether we get the response after every second

Tags: java, wait

I need to poll on the response of the endpoint for a total time say 40 sec and have to check after the interval of 1 sec every time if I get the response. Is there any method already defined in java to do so
Any class interface that can be used to do so?

I am new to this concept

Comment: You could either send the request you want to send or use [InetAddress#isReachable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)).

Comment: @dan1st I need something which checks at every sec if we get the response

Comment: There is [ScheduledService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) from javafx, you could potentially use that.